# Summing in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this mongodb collection

```
   {
       "_id": "5ab93bd8bca5b3568ad93bc6",
       "name": "abc",
       "id":"1",
       "price": 300000,
       "__v": 0
   }
   {
       "_id": "5ab9d8bca5b334328ad934c1",
       "name": "cde",
       "id":"1",
       "price": 200000,
       "__v": 0
   }
```

I want to write a query to get the sum of the prices from all the documents from the collection. How could I do that?

Please use this route format. Regards

```
router.get('/values/:id', (req, res, next)=>{
    Value.count({ id: req.params.id }, function(err, value){
        res.json(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to right a query to get the sum of price from all the documents
>   from the collection

So why does your route require an ID?

Anyways, use aggregation particularly [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

```
router.get('/values/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Value.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { id: req.params.id }
        },
        { 
            $group: {
                _id: "id",
                total: { $sum: "$price" }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, value){
        console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I wanted to sum all values which have the same id, i have updated the collection above.

Comment: @Dng It's been awhile but I think you need to use also [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Comment: router.get('/campaign_sum/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Campaign.aggregate([
        { $match : { vendorID : req.params.id } },
        { 
            $group: {
                _id: "id",
                total: { $sum: "$budget" }
            }
        }
    ], function (err, value){
        res.json(value);
    });
});

Comment: @Dng If it doesn't work with the match, it might mean the field doesn't exist or no match was found. In your comment, the 1st [stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation-pipeline) should filter out all campaign documents with `vendorID` matching `req.params.id` and the 2nd stage should sum the `budget` using the filtered documents grouping by `id`. Try analyzing the documents for each stage to see if you are getting the expected results (like if you are testing 1st stage, comment out 2nd stage and check if the results are correct).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
 {$group:{"_id":{$sum:"$price"}}}
])
```